# Using offline mode of scorm and tracking the results of each user

Tags: scorm1.2

My scenario is I will download the course and work offline on that course. can we track the results of the course and store it some where? So that i can upload the status of the course when i connected to the LMS?

Can we implement the offline course(single course) for multiple users? If so how can we authenticate each user and store them?

Please explain me the steps of doing so.

Currently I am using HTML-5, Javascript, Scorm1.2 on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

There is no standard (SCORM-specified) way to handle offline course/SCOs.  However, there is nothing that prohibits the use case.  To support offline use, you'll need to  support a few different aspects of SCORM on the client side (and/or via a component of the LMS installed on the users computer).

Some LMSs already provide offline player functionality.  If you are already using a specific LMS, I would contact your vendor or open source community to see if an offline player already exists.  If you are developing a custom solution, here is some information that may help.

**Run-Time Environment (RTE)**
The SCORM RTE consists of the API and Data Model.  The LMS is responsible for providing a handle to the API, in the document object model (DOM) of a browser -- in a pre-defined location.  There is typically an active connection to the LMS through the API.  The SCO (content) then communicates with the LMS via this API object.  This object is called "API" in SCORM 1.2.  The client side data is then persisted, server-side, in the LMS data store, but this process is implementation-specific and varies across LMSs.  For example, LMS vendors could use Web Sockets, Web Service calls, ADL's new technology *the Experience API* (http://www.adlnet.gov/tla/experience-api/), or really anything to move the data from the client side to the server side on LMSCommit or LMSFinish.

*How to handle offline RTE -* 
For a single SCO in a course, your client-side API could be "smart" enough to get a set of initialized data model elements when online, then persist them, client side (or in an LMS component installed locally on the users machine).  Then then API could have the logic to respond to SCO requests as if it were the server-side LMS responding.  Requirements on how an LMS responds to SCO requests are available in the RTE book.  Then when back online, the client-side LMS component could sync with the server side component of the LMS using web services, web sockets, the Experience API, etc (again, this is implementation specific and outside the scope of SCORM).

**Content Aggregation Model (CAM)**
The good news is the CAM in SCORM Version 1.2 is much simpler than the CAM in SCORM 2004 since there is no (or actually very light) navigation and sequencing.  So, if you wanted to download a complete course (or courses) so it was available offline, the imsmanifest.xml file detailed in the SCORM CAM book would give you the structure and list of resources used in the course.  Your offline player would have to have the functionality to understand this structure and deliver local copies of the content when offline.  This player most likely includes a table of contents of the course and/or previous and next buttons so the user can traverse through the course modules.  The offline player would control this traversal per the structure detailed in the imsmanifest.xml file(s).

When an individual SCO is launched by the player, the Run-Time Environment (RTE) component discussed above is included in the browser DOM, responds to SCO requests and syncs back up to the LMS when a connection is available.

**Additional Information**

For details on SCORM RTE and CAM requirements, see the SCORM Version 1.2 documentation available at http://www.adlnet.gov/resources/SCORM-1-2-Specification?type=technical_documentation